# linear equations with three unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a system of linear equations with three unknown $x, y, z$ whose solutions are:
>
> ---
>
> $x = 6+5t,$
> $y = 4 + 3t,$
> and $z = 2 + t$

**where t is an arbitrary constant**.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You’re expected to do a bit more on this site than post what looks like a bare homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $t=z-2$ into equations $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$x=6+5(z-2)$$
$$y=4+3(z-2)$$

Comment: If we consider a linear combination of the given system then comparing for $t$ and the constant terms in both sides we have $x-2y+z=0$

Answer (score 0):

You could have also used a matrix and put it in row echelon form, hence solving it Gaussian elimination. Here is a Khan Academy video explaining this: [Khan Academy Video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/solving-equations-with-inverse-matrices/v/solving-matrix-equation)